# Accessing Dynamic Arrays Through Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a novice programmer learning C++.

I have an assignment in which an input txt file is provided with 16 lines of 1-5 digit numbers with 5 numbers max in each row. We are supposed to write a function findmax to use in main to output the max number in each row into another txt file.

My code has no current compiling errors I'm more just stuck on how to actually utilize this function in main and pass it into the outuput file. Sorry again if this is really simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int *make( int n)
{
#if 0
    int *a = new int[n];
#else
    int a[n];
#endif
    for( int i=0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = i;

    return a;
 }

int findmax(int x1,int x2,int x3,int x4, int x5)
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        int n, temp;
        int a[i];
        if(a[i]>temp)
            temp=a[i];
        return temp;
    }

}
int main() 
{
    int n;
    int x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5;
    cout << "Enter number of lines n in the input file." << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int *a = make(n);

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cout << a[i] << " "; cout << endl;

    ifstream infile; infile.open("/home/labs/lab4/lab4_input.txt");
    ofstream outfile; outfile.open("/home/labs/lab4/lab4_output.txt");
    if( !infile.is_open()) cout << "open infile failed\n";

    infile >> x1 >> x2 >> x3 >> x4 >> x5;
    findmax( x1, x2, x3, x4, x5);
    outfile << y1 << " " << y2 << " " << y3 << " " << y4 << " " << y5 << endl;
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to crack open your C++ textbook and read the chapter about arrays. This site cannot teach you such basic concepts. Your program compiles by sheer accident (because you are using wrong compilation flags).

Comment: In your `make` function the `int a[n];` is create a Variable Length Array (VLA) which is not part of the standard C++ language.  Search the internet for "c++ array dynamic memory new".

Comment: Use std::vector!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you say you are supposed to read and write to a file but when you use `cin` and `cout` you are actually using standard input and output. You need to look into reading and writing into files in C++.
Secondly, in the `findmax` function you are passing 5 arguments which you never use and also declare a variable `n` which you never use. Also the loop at the end of the `make` function makes no sense. You need to read each line separately, store the numbers in an array and then use the `findmax` function passing that array as an argument. You then output the result for that line in the output file.